# Please suggest some books about Computational Geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, computational-geometry

Please suggest good books on computational geometry.

Comment: Please use whole words, not text message shortcuts.

Comment: What happens if you search "computational geometry" on *Amazon.com* and read the reviews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like ***Discrete and Computational Geometry*** by Satyan L. Devadoss  and Joseph O'Rourke—very clear and well illustrated.  A nice touch is including "unsolved problems," which motivates students and shows this is a very living discipline.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  take a look at 
this 
one:https://ia600905.us.archive.org/25/items/ComputationalGeometryAlgorithmsAndApplications2e/Computational_Geometry_-_Algorithms_and_Applications_2e.pdf